# Is there a better way than boolean for function arguments?

Tags: python

My function is:

```
def names(N=None, p=None, gender=None, start=None, End=None, Interval=None):
```

And what this function does take the arguments and provide an output obviously. But if `N` is `None`, but `p` is given and all other arguments are `Non` or if `N` and `P` are given and all other arguments are not given, and such a map goes on, that is if one argument is given and other one is not given the output is supposed to vary. Currently I'm using an if statement and boolean to check for it. But since there are so many arguments it's being a really long number probabilities. Hence is there an easier way of doing it?

Currently I am trying:

```
#assuming N argument is not given but p argument is given
if ((bool(N)==False) and (bool(p)==True))==True:
#then the operation is carried out.
```

Comment: First to be more pythonic you should test variable as being - or not being - `None` as follow: `if N is None and p is not None`. Also having less parameters passed to the method - by splitting it for example - might help

Comment: `>>> bool('')`
`False`
`>>> bool(0)`
`False`
`>>> bool([])`
`False`

Comment: When you set default arguments to None, it is best practice to check ``if N is None``

Comment: Can you decompose this into multiple functions which call `names` instead?

Comment: @bvidal You can go even further and just go `if p and not N` as recommended in `pep-0008`

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr it does work too but I've always been septical regarding this way of testing as it seems less explicit than testing against `None`. Also [python.org](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) seems to indicate that using `if p` is not recommended

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having the `names` method accept either an **object** with `N`, `p`, `gender`, etc. properties, or a **dictionary** with those keys. You could then test if the object's properties, or the dictionary's keys, are set.

The object `getattr()` method or the dictionary `.get()` method will even let you set default values, or you could set default values in the object's `__init__()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider splitting the function into several functions that accept less number of parameters (aim for "high cohesion and loose coupling" as a guide in splitting the parameters).

If you convert all parameters to bool then you could exploit that `True == 1` and `False == 0` e.g.:

```
result = [['false N, false p', 'false N, true p'], 
          ['true N, false p', 'true N, true p']][N][p]
```

You could use the matrix to choose a function to call instead of choosing a string.